# Join to table with two or more records with the same foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have three tables

User

```
id
name
```

Report

```
id
id_user
comments
```

ReportedUser

```
id
id_report
id_user
```

I want to list each report and its reported users, but I do not know how to do the correct query.

I have used Inner Join, but it show all records from ReportedUser table, showing twice or more (depending how reported users are in a report) the same report.

I know I can do that inside of the programming language (PHP), but I need filter the information with LIKE operator and more. Is it possible to do it in MySQL?

Comment: show your table data with architecture and far you have tried yet

Comment: Pls see the following guidance how to ask a good sql related question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query At the moment I do not understand your question, since an inner join with ReportedUser table does list each report and reported users. Pls be specific as to what you have tried, what that try has resulted in, and what your end results should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your data looks something like this

```
drop table if exists report;
create table report(id int, name varchar(3));
insert into report values
(1,'abc'),(2,'def'),(3,'ghi');

drop table if exists report_user;
create table report_user (user_id int, report_id int);

insert into report_user values
(1,1),(1,2),
(2,1),
(3,1),(3,3);
```

You could use group_concat

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select r.id,r.name report, group_concat(u.username order by u.username asc) useby
    -> from report r
    -> join report_user ru on ru.report_id = r.id
    -> join users u on u.id = ru.user_id
    -> group by r.id,r.name
    -> ;
+------+--------+---------------+
| id   | report | useby         |
+------+--------+---------------+
|    1 | abc    | Ali,Jane,John |
|    2 | def    | John          |
|    3 | ghi    | Ali           |
+------+--------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

or conversely

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select u.id,u.username, group_concat(r.name order by r.name asc) reportsused
    -> from users u
    -> join report_user ru on ru.user_id = u.id
    -> join report r on r.id = ru.report_id
    -> group by u.id,u.username
    -> ;
+----+----------+-------------+
| id | username | reportsused |
+----+----------+-------------+
|  1 | John     | abc,def     |
|  2 | Jane     | abc         |
|  3 | Ali      | abc,ghi     |
+----+----------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks! I needed that. How can I select your answer as solution?